# Operating System Not Found, Media Test Failure Check Cable, BIOS Shows 10GB HDD Size

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I have a Dell Inspiron 1564 laptop. my harddisk partitions are not visible when i try to install OS.

In the BIOS the **HDD size is 10GB** only. But my laptop had 320GB.

**on boot it shows:**

> PXE ROM "Media test Failure- Check cable"
>   Operating system not found.

**on running dell diagnostics it shows:**

> Hard Drive DST Short Test - Test Results: Not Applicable.

Also, If i insert a live cd, the partitions i had are not visible. When i am trying to install a new copy of OS, there is no partition to select.

Comment: This is connected to network boot.  You can disable it in your BIOS.

Comment: I went to boot priority settings and disabled network. The PXE ROM error is gone now. but, Still i get operating system not found error and the harddisk size is still showing 10GB in BIOS. and also i can't see any partitions to install OS again. And start up repair isn't working.

Comment: Try switching the hard drive to a different SATA port, changing SATA cables, and running your hard drive test tool between each. This sounds like your hard drive may have failed.